# How do I suppress m2e warnings?

Tags: java, warnings, m2e

So I installed m2e for eclipse and I'm now getting a warning on my pom file.  It says "maven-enforcer-plugin (goal "enforce") is ignored by m2e."  I'm searching through the preferences and I don't see anything that will help me suppress this specific warning.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't want to change my pom file, by the way.  This pom file is owned by the team and not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is currently not possible without altering the pom.xml file. This this page in the Eclipse wiki:

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

However, there is currently some work done for storing such information outside of the pom:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350414